# How to sort a pandas dataframe by a column that has both numbers and strings?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
         col0         col1  col2   col4
         1    '1ZE7999'  865545   20    20
         2    'R022428'  865584  297     0
         3    34         865665  296     0 
         4    56         865700  297     0
         5    100        865628  292     5
```

I want to sort it by 'col0', first the numerical values, then the strings, the way that Excel sorts

```
       col0         col1  col2   col4
  3    34         865665  296     0 
  4    56         865700  297     0
  5    100        865628  292     5
  1    '1ZE7999'  865545   20    20
  2    'R022428'  865584  297     0
```

I used

```
df.sort_values(by='col1', ascending=True)
```

But that does not sort it that way, it sorts it from 0-9 then a-z

```
      col0         col1  col2   col4
 1    '1ZE7999'  865545   20    20
 5    100        865628  292     5
 3    34         865665  296     0 
 4    56         865700  297     0
 2    'R022428'  865584  297     0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort descending an alphanumeric pandas index.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528850/how-to-sort-descending-an-alphanumeric-pandas-index)

Comment: Hmm, do the strings need to be sorted as well? Or is it okay if they just come after the numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pd.to_numeric` + `sort_values` + `loc` -

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.col0, errors='coerce').sort_values().index]

        col0    col1  col2  col4
3         34  865665   296     0
4         56  865700   297     0
5        100  865628   292     5
1  '1ZE7999'  865545    20    20
2  'R022428'  865584   297     0
```

---

**Details**

`pd.to_numeric` coerces non-integral values to `NaN` -

```
i = pd.to_numeric(df.col0, errors='coerce')
i

1      NaN
2      NaN
3     34.0
4     56.0
5    100.0
Name: col0, dtype: float64
```

`sort_values` sorts the column, ignoring NaNs.

```
j = i.sort_values()
j

3     34.0
4     56.0
5    100.0
1      NaN
2      NaN
Name: col0, dtype: float64
```

Observe the index. All you need to do is use the index to *reindex* the dataframe. Either `loc` or `reindex` will do it.

```
df.loc[j.index]

        col0    col1  col2  col4
3         34  865665   296     0
4         56  865700   297     0
5        100  865628   292     5
1  '1ZE7999'  865545    20    20
2  'R022428'  865584   297     0
```

```
df.reindex(index=j.index)

        col0    col1  col2  col4
3         34  865665   296     0
4         56  865700   297     0
5        100  865628   292     5
1  '1ZE7999'  865545    20    20
2  'R022428'  865584   297     0
```

If you need to reset the index, that's easily done.

```
df.loc[j.index].reset_index(drop=True)

        col0    col1  col2  col4
0         34  865665   296     0
1         56  865700   297     0
2        100  865628   292     5
3  '1ZE7999'  865545    20    20
4  'R022428'  865584   297     0
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `natsort`

```
from natsort import natsorted

df.set_index('col0').reindex(natsorted(df.col0.tolist(), key=lambda y: y.lower())).reset_index()
Out[736]: 
        col0    col1  col2  col4
0         34  865665   296     0
1         56  865700   297     0
2        100  865628   292     5
3  '1ZE7999'  865545    20    20
4  'R022428'  865584   297     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `index_humansorted` from `natsort`

```
import natsort
df = df.iloc[natsort.index_humansorted(df['col0'])]
```