# Custom sorting columns in multi level pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

#### Background

I have a big data frame with 2 levels columns, but 1 level rows, and I am trying to sort it as follows:
level 0: alphabetically;
level 1: custom sort.

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
dictionary = {'A' : {'M': [1,2,3,4,5],
                     'L': [6,7,8,9,1],
                     'F': [3,5,1,3,5]  },
              'C' : {'M': [2,3,4,5,6],
                     'L': [7,8,9,1,2],
                     'F': [0,1,6,3,5]  },
              'B' : {'M': [1,5,2,5,3],
                     'L': [9,5,6,3,4],
                     'F': [6,2,7,1,5] }
         }
reform = {(outerKey, innerKey): values for outerKey, innerDict in dictionary.iteritems() for innerKey, values in innerDict.iteritems()}
pd.DataFrame(reform,index=['g','h','i','j','k'])
```

What I have then is

```
#        A          B           C
#        F  L   M   F   L   M   F   L   M
#    g  3   6   1   6   9   1   0   7   2
#    h  5   7   2   2   5   5   1   8   3
#    i  1   8   3   7   6   2   6   9   4
#    j  3   9   4   1   3   5   3   1   5
#    k  5   1   5   5   4   3   5   2   6
```

#### Question

How can I specify the order of columns to be A, B, C on level 0 and F, M, L on level 1?

```
### OUT
#        A          B           C
#        F  M   L   F   M   L   F   M   L
```

I was trying with `pd.IndexSlice` and `.loc`, but I still get only alphabetic order.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html), this accepts a labels arg, axis and level:

```
In [20]:
df = df.reindex_axis(list('FML'), axis=1, level=1)
df

Out[20]:
   A        B        C      
   F  M  L  F  M  L  F  M  L
g  3  1  6  6  1  9  0  2  7
h  5  2  7  2  5  5  1  3  8
i  1  3  8  7  2  6  6  4  9
j  3  4  9  1  5  3  3  5  1
k  5  5  1  5  3  4  5  6  2
```

Thanks to @Nickli Maveli you can also use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to achieve the same:

```
In [22]:
df = df.reindex(columns=list('FML'), level=1)
df

Out[22]:
   A        B        C      
   F  M  L  F  M  L  F  M  L
g  3  1  6  6  1  9  0  2  7
h  5  2  7  2  5  5  1  3  8
i  1  3  8  7  2  6  6  4  9
j  3  4  9  1  5  3  3  5  1
k  5  5  1  5  3  4  5  6  2
```

Comment: @jezrael What problem, the OP want's the column order to change, not just re-label them is my understanding

Comment: Sorry, I was bad.

Comment: `df.reindex(columns=list("FML"), level=1)` should be enough. But anyways, nice answer.

Comment: @jezrael no worries, originally I thought this was just a simple `.columns.set_levels` problem but I looked again

Comment: Yes, I see original. And it was bad I think

Comment: @NickilMaveli sure more than one way to skin a cat here, will add for completeness, I think `reindex_axis` is more flexible which is why I prefer it but `reindex` is less typing

Comment: @NickilMaveli actually it looks like `reindex` offers more but the docstrings shows initially `kwargs` which is why I thought it was less flexible

Comment: @EdChum: never mind. Now that you've figured that out completely :-)

Comment: Haha, the whole pandas elite really rolled out for this answer.

Comment: @jezrael @NickilMaveli Would the `df.reindex(columns=list("FML"))`method still work if the `F M L` columns labels are on level 0? I got the result `F F F M M M L L L` in that scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Setting index on dataframe creation

If you do not want to change the dataframe afterwards, you can give the `pd.DataFrame` constructor an index where you define the order already.

#### Explicit solution

```
columns = pd.Index([('A', 'F'), ('A', 'M'), ('A', 'L'), ('B', 'F'), ('B', 'M'), ('B', 'L'),('C', 'F'), ('C', 'M'), ('C', 'L')])
pd.DataFrame(reform,index=['g','h','i','j','k'], columns=columns)
```

#### Composite solution

```
columns = pd.Index([(level_0, level_1) for level_0 in "ABC" for level_1 in "FML"])
pd.DataFrame(reform,index=['g','h','i','j','k'], columns=columns)
```

#### Both gives

```
   A        B        C      
   F  M  L  F  M  L  F  M  L
g  3  1  6  6  1  9  0  2  7
h  5  2  7  2  5  5  1  3  8
i  1  3  8  7  2  6  6  4  9
j  3  4  9  1  5  3  3  5  1
k  5  5  1  5  3  4  5  6  2
```