# Custom sorting of the level 1 index of a multiindex Pandas DataFrame according to the level 0 index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multindex DataFrame, `df`:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one', 'two']]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([8, 4]), index=arrays)
```

which looks like:

```
             0    1    2    3
bar one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
baz one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    three  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    four   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
foo one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

I now need to sort the '`baz`' sub-level into a new order, to create something that looks like `df_end`:

```
arrays_end = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo'],
              ['one', 'two', 'two', 'four', 'three', 'one', 'one', 'two']]

df_end = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([8, 4]), index=arrays_end)
```

which looks like:

```
             0    1    2    3
bar one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
baz two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    four   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    three  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
foo one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

I thought that I might be able to reindex the `baz` row:

```
new_index = ['two','four','three','one']

df.loc['baz'].reindex(new_index)
```

Which gives:

```
         0    1    2    3
two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
four   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
three  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

...and insert these values back into the original DataFrame:

```
df.loc['baz'] = df.loc['baz'].reindex(new_index)
```

But the result is:

```
             0    1    2    3
bar one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
baz one    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    two    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    three  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    four   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
foo one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Which is not what I'm looking for! So my question is how I can use `new_index` to reorder the rows in the `baz` index. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems a better solution for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073254/custom-sorting-columns-in-multi-level-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: (to fit the desired layout)

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one', 'two']]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(32).reshape([8, 4]), index=arrays)
new_baz_index = [('baz', i) for i in ['two','four','three','one']]
index = df.index.values.copy()
index[df.index.get_loc('baz')] = new_baz_index
df.reindex(index)
```

`df.index.get_loc('baz')` will get the location of the `baz` part as a slice object and we replace the part there only.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your incredibly quick and helpful reply Tai. This is excellent :)

Comment: @tomp no problem. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Update :-)

```
pd.concat([df[df.index.get_level_values(level=0)!='baz'],df.reindex(list(zip(['baz']*4,['two','four','three','one'])))])
Out[1156]: 
             0    1    2    3
bar one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
foo one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
baz two    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    four   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    three  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    one    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Hi again Wen, and thanks for looking at this! The `df` in your answer matches the input `df` in my question, rather than the output. Is there a missing step?